# Working with argparse need explaination of how to use it properly

Tags: python, django, argparse

I have 3 questions.

1). I would like to be able to use this python commandline program without worrying about order of the arguments. I was using sys.argv before and had my users use this script like this: 
`mypyscript.py create indexname http://localhost:9260 clientMap.json`
That requires my users to remember the order. 
I want something like this: 
`mypyscript.py -i indexname -c create -f clientMap.json -u http://localhost:9260`
Notice how I have mutilated the order.

2). What commandline variable in my program will I be using as the conditional logic 
    in my code? Will I need to access it via args.command-type? The dash is okay?

3). Only the file-to-index is the optional parameter. Can I pass to add_argument some optional = True parameter or something? How can I deal with that?

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c","--command-type", help="The command to run against ElasticSearch are one of these: create|delete|status")
parser.add_argument("-i","--index_name", help="Name of ElasticSearch index to run the command against")
parser.add_argument("-u", "--elastic-search-url", help="Base URl of ElasticSearch")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file_to_index", default = 'false', help="The file name of the index map")

args = parser.parse_args()


print args.elastic_search_url
```

Comment: Just use [docopt](http://docopt.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What is the question here? Personally I think it depends on the use case, there is something to be said for your old system. Especially when used with subparsers.
2. The dash is the default and commonly understood way
3. There is a `required=True` argument which tells `argparse` what to require.

For the `command-type` I would recommend using the `choices` parameter so it will be automatically constrained to `create,delete,status`

Also, in the case of the url you could consider adding a regular expression to validate, you can add this using the `type` parameter.

Here's my version of your argument code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '-c',
    '--command-type',
    required=True,
    help='The command to run against ElasticSearch',
    choices=('create', 'delete', 'status'),
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-i',
    '--index_name',
    required=True,
    help='Name of ElasticSearch index to run the command against',
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-u',
    '--elastic-search-url',
    required=True,
    help='Base URl of ElasticSearch',
)
parser.add_argument(
    '-f',
    '--file_to_index',
    type=argparse.FileType(),
    help='The file name of the index map',
)


args = parser.parse_args()

print args
```

I believe that should work as you expect it to.

Comment: I've provided you the usecase in question 1. I'm new to python and definitely argparse. Could you please elaborate? My real concern is question 1 as it relates to question 3. I don't have required=True in any of the add_argument method's parameters. And i get an error saying too few args.

Comment: Can you try the version I have just posted? I believe it should do what you want :)

Comment: The `FileType` use might be confusing for beginner.

Comment: Eventually you might want to make `command_type` a subparser.  This would be most useful if different commands require different parameters.

Comment: @hpaulj: it might be a bit confusing but I still think it's better to use the right tool for the job from the beginning :) And the manual is fairly clear about these things I think.

Comment: My impression is the `FileType` is intended more as a convenience and example of a specialized `type` than a 'must-use' tool.  It doesn't fit with the newer Python use of contexts, which open and close files.  In http://bugs.python.org/msg166068  the creator of `argparse` talks about the ideal use of `FileType`, and the need for something better.

Comment: @hpaulj: I wasn't aware of the closing problems but I have to say that in most real life scripts I have seen so far that didn't bother to close the file descriptors it was never really a problem. It's not a good idea but for simple scripts convenience and simplicity also counts :) Personally I would have expected argparse to do an `is_readable` type of test instead of returning a file descriptor.